# how to compare html table two columns values and highlight the unmatched data with color?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my html table. I want to highlight the unmatched data with color. I have written javascript for that but it works only for the first row. It's not working for the remaining rows. Please help me about this logic.

sample output Image:

[image]

```js
highlight($("#new"), $("#old"));

function highlight(newElem, oldElem) {
  var newText = newElem.text();
  var oldText = oldElem.text();
  var text = "";
  newElem.text().split("").forEach(function(value, index) {
    if (value != oldText.charAt(index))
      text += "<span class='highlight'>" + value + "</span>";
    else
      text += value;
  });
  newElem.html(text);
}
```

```css
.highlight {
  color: red;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tdata">
  <tr class="tvalue">
    <th>S.No</th>
    <th>VALUE1</th>
    <th>VALUE2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="tvalue">
    <td>1</td>
    <td id="old">this is veerendar</td>
    <td id="new">this is vearander</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="tvalue">
    <td>2</td>
    <td id="old">123456789</td>
    <td id="new">124353789</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="tvalue">
    <td>3</td>
    <td id="old">12 34 56 78 32 45</td>
    <td id="new">34 23 56 79 32 46</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="tvalue">
    <td>4</td>
    <td id="old">ab cd ef sd ef wd</td>
    <td id="new">bc er ef sd ef we</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You cannot have multiple elements with the same id in a html-document. Use css-classes instead. Loop throught the rows in the table and run your function for all the rows.

Comment: Please send the sample loop for above html table and apply my logic on loop. Please help me.

Comment: You can do that yourself and learn! You can use [jQuery each](https://api.jquery.com/each/) -method for this.

Comment: Actually i dont have knowledge on jquery . Please send me sample code for me. Please

Comment: Sorry, this is not a free coding service. You don't need a knowledge to learn something new, so go and try it out and learn.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for sharing this code snippet. It really helped me.
I tried this and it worked for me. The changes I had to make were add a number at the end of id or class whatever you are using. Since my page was generated from a script I didn't have any problem adding a number at the end.

```js
$( ".tvalue" ).each(function( i ) {
        highlight($("#new"+i), $("#old"+i));
      });

function highlight(newElem, oldElem) {
  var newText = newElem.text();
  var oldText = oldElem.text();
  var text = "";
  newElem.text().split("").forEach(function(value, index) {
    if (value != oldText.charAt(index))
      text += "<span class='highlight'>" + value + "</span>";
    else
      text += value;
  });
  newElem.html(text);
}
```

```css
.highlight {
  color: red;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tdata">
  <tr class="tvalue">
    <th>S.No</th>
    <th>VALUE1</th>
    <th>VALUE2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="tvalue">
    <td>1</td>
    <td id="old1">this is veerendar</td>
    <td id="new1">this is vearander</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="tvalue">
    <td>2</td>
    <td id="old2">123456789</td>
    <td id="new2">124353789</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="tvalue">
    <td>3</td>
    <td id="old3">12 34 56 78 32 45</td>
    <td id="new3">34 23 56 79 32 46</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="tvalue">
    <td>4</td>
    <td id="old4">ab cd ef sd ef wd</td>
    <td id="new4">bc er ef sd ef we</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZsUm.png)